# How do I format some code specifically for the language used? Or how do I prevent it from being formatted? Which languages are supported?

Tags: support, editing, code-formatting

If I format some code by indenting it using four spaces, the code is not formatted. How do I format some code specifically for the language used? Or how do I prevent it from being formatted? Which languages are supported?

Answer (score 18):

Add the line `<!-- language: <language_string> -->` (where `<language_string>` is the string identifying the language) before the start of the code, and make sure that the code itself has an empty line before it:

```
<!-- language: <language_string> -->

    ...
    <line 1>
    <line 2>
    <line 3>
    ...
```

<sub>*<language_string> = string identifying the language</sub>

As suggested by [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru), if you want to prevent the code from being formatted instead, you can add the line `<!-- language: none -->`:

```
<!-- language: none -->

    # ...
    echo This snippet will not be nicely formatted when copy-pasted inside a post
    # ...
```

`bash` example:

```
<!-- language: bash -->

    # ...
    echo This snippet will be nicely formatted when copy-pasted inside a post
    # ...
```

Courtesy of [terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon), here's the list of the currently supported languages along with their identifying string (most of the languages listed won't need the `lang-` prefix):

```
none:      none
bash:      lang-bash OR lang-bsh
c:         lang-c
clj:       lang-clj
coffee:    lang-coffee
cpp:       lang-cpp
cs:        lang-cs
csh:       lang-csh
css:       lang-css
dart:      lang-dart
erlang:    lang-erlang
go:        lang-go
hs:        lang-hs
html:      lang-html
java:      lang-java
js:        lang-js
latex:     lang-latex
lisp:      lang-lisp
lua:       lang-lua
ml:        lang-ml
pascal:    lang-pascal
perl:      lang-perl
php:       lang-php
proto:     lang-proto
py:        lang-py
r:         lang-r
rb:        lang-rb
regex:     lang-regex
rust:      lang-rust
scala:     lang-scala
sh:        lang-sh
sql:       lang-sql
vb:        lang-vb
vhdl:      lang-vhdl
xml:       lang-xml
```

Finally, if the question is tagged with [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash), [python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python), or [php](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php) - any of the ones listed above in fact, it will automatically format it. Example: [What is the syntax for IF/ELSE in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612100/help-me-with-if-condition).

As [explained](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13900/how-do-i-format-some-code-specifically-for-the-language-used-or-how-do-i-preven/13901?noredirect=1#comment24085_13901) by @Braiam, the `lang-` prefix is needed for those languages that are not associated with any tag.

Comment: It turns out that `lang-bash` also works, despite only `lang-bsh` being listed.

Comment: @terdon Thanks, I updated it

Comment: Why is there no BASIC in there? @terdon

Comment: For plenty of languages, you don't need the `lang-` at all.

Comment: @muru I think the `lang-` is optional for all of them.

Comment: @muru Thanks, but the `<pre></pre>` blocks were meant to show the empty lines at the end of the snippet

Comment: @Rinzwind no idea. Also notice the conspicuous and unexplainable absence of `lang-whitespace`!

Comment: @terdon Unless it's a bug, not for `lang-sql`

Comment: @kos you don't need empty lines at the end of a snippet. You do need an empty line before the `<!-- language` line.

Comment: @muru You're right, updated

Comment: @kos yeah, some do work without it but not all.

Comment: @terdon Also no Brainfuck support. Believe it or not, [people writes PHP interpreters with it](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-BrainFuck)

Comment: @Tim Didn't know about that, I think you should add another answer to this question ;)

Comment: @kos nah, it can all go in one :)

Comment: There is a question over on MetaSE that has a answer on how to use syntax highlighting features: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108 . Google's prettify is used, for which the README is currently [here](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) (it may move to [here](https://github.com/google/google-code-prettify)). BASIC is apparently available by extensions, which SE may be able to add :)

Comment: @terdon the lang- prefix is required unless there's a tag associated with the language, ie. you can type either `python` or `lang-python` for python would work, but only `pip` would work as the tag is associated (at least on SO) with the lang-python formating. If a tag, like [tag:scala] doesn't have associated a formating at the end of the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info "like python does") then neither adding the tag, nor just "scala" would work, you will have to type `lang-scala`.